# Communication Java to NodeJS?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I am exploring various ways that allow Java to connect and communicate with NodeJS. An example of what I am trying to achieve, is for example call Java methods from NodeJS, while allowing the Java method to manipulate Javascript objects. I know the JSObject class is helpful for this purpose. I have also heard so far of Dnode and ZeroMQ. Have you heard of or do you have experience in doing something similar? Would you suggest a way on how this communication Java to NodejS can be done?

Comment: There are lots of ways, from opening a socket to sharing data storage at a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with an agnostic implementation.

A rest server on node js, maybe using [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) listening for messages

A http client on the java side as [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) to send messages to node.

this will also make it dead easy to test node implementation with curl and static requests; will enable you to implement authentication later on using any standard mechanism from oauth to basic and will let you change the client and the dispatcher independently later on

also you will be able to put any kind of standard load balancer in between, should you need the node app to scale.